# Turning a Sum Into an Integral

Tags: real-analysis, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables, probability-limit-theorems

I came up with a measure of dispersion for a sequence of $n$ numbers $(x_i)$, namely $\sqrt{\sum^n_{i=1}x^2_i - \sum^n_{j=2}\sum^{j-1}_{i=1}\frac{2x_i x_j}{n-1}}$.  Is there a way to generalize this sum by turning it into an integral for probability distribution functions?

Comment: Assuming $x_i$'s are i.i.d. samples from a distribution $\mu$ with finite first moment, SLLN tells that we have $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2-\sum_{j=2}^{n}\sum_{i=1}^{j-1}\frac{2x_ix_j}{n-1}} \to \sqrt{\mathbf{E}[x^2]-\mathbf{E}[x]^2} = \sigma_\mu$$ almost surely, where $\sigma_f \in [0, \infty]$ is the standard deviation of the distribution $\mu$.

Comment: Would we also require $\mu$ to have a finite second moment since $\sum^n_{j=2}\sum^{j-1}_{i=1}\frac{2x_i x_j}{n(n-1)} = \sum^n_{j=1}\sum^n_{i=1}\frac{x_i x_j}{n(n-1)} -\sum^n_{i=1}\frac{x_i^2}{n(n-1)}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Sangchul Lee’s reply, I was able to deduce that if I scale my original calculation by a factor of $\frac{\sqrt{n-1}}{n}$, then my scaled equation becomes identical to the standard deviation of the set, regardless of the $n$ chosen.